# How to display different parts of Ajax responses in induvidual html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

At first I did my validations with multiple Ajax request and optimized with some help and I send all of my data and do all of my success functionality in one AJAX request. But doing that gives multiple results. Now each inputs validation inside of every div elements. It's not showing validations one by one. I tried to array my errors with json but it didnt work either. I think the problem is in Ajax area what I missing?

[image: Screenshot of my issue]

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

        $('#submit').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var submit = "1";
            
            $.ajax({
                url: 'registercontrol.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    fullname : fullname,
                    username : username,
                    email : email,
                    password : password,
                    submit : submit
                },
                success:function(response){                 
                    $("#vfullname").html(response);
                    $("#vusername").html(response);
                    $("#vemail").html(response);
                    $("#vpassword").html(response);  
                }
            });                     
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: We can not possibly answer this without knowing what the response to your AJAX request is in the first place.

Comment: Well, clearly, because you've put the same response in all of the outputs: `$("#vfullname").html(response);$("#vusername").html(response);...` - you need to separate the response as required, eg `$("#vfullname").html(response.vfullname) **but** that depends on how you add the errors to the response - you need to **add the response errors in a way that can be separated**

Comment: See my working solution below and some explanation to have your code simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your previous question where you got to know about how to a single ajax request and data to it.

I also saw your `PHP` file code in which you are doing validation  - if the fields like `fullname`, `username`, `password`, `email` are empty. You are doing all the validation at the backend side in PHP which is an overkill of doing multiple `ajax` request to check empty field via PHP.

You can easily achieve this by doing the required field validation on the `frontend` like this below using `if` and `else` and only send data via ajax to your Database code once you have everything to send.

Once all the fields are filled in by the user. You can send them via the ajax on `else` statement just like i am doing below.
I have also added messages if user did not filled in anything in the input on the screen.

Once your data is all validated you can get the `response` back from `ajax` and show success on on the frontend `div`

You can merge this code into yours code to apply your own `CSS` and `HTML` input

I have recreated the exact example for you.

Just run snippet to see it all working below.

```js
$('#submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var submit = "1";

  if (!fullname) {
    $('.response').html('Full Name is a required field')
  } else if (!username) {
    $('.response').html('Username is a required field')
  } else if (!email) {
    $('.response').html('Email is a required field')
  } else if (!password) {
    $('.response').html('Password is required field')
  } else {
    //Do Ajax and
    $('.response').html('')
    console.log('Doing Ajax Request Now')
    $.ajax({
      url: 'registercontrol.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        fullname: fullname,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        submit: submit
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $(".response").html(response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

.response {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  Name <input type="text" id="fullname" /> Username <input type="text" id="username" /> Email <input type="text" id="email" /> Password <input type="email" id="password" />

  <button id="submit">Submit</button>


  <div class="response"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, now this thing really made sense and I figur it out.

Comment: @Ulrich Glad to hear that i could help you. Cheers.